# Type '(item: T) => Element' is not assignable to type '((item: T) => ReactNode) & string'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a problem with types. After upgrading to React 18, I get the following error for the component `ItemsList`.

```
            <ItemsList items={items} dataTestId='items_list_block'>
              {(item) => ( // error
                <ItemView
                  item={item}
                />
              )}
            </ItemsList>          </ItemsList>
```

ItemsList:

```
type tItemsListProps<T extends tOptionListItem> = {
  children: (item: T) => React.ReactNode;
  items: T[];
  dataTestId?: string;
};

function ItemsList<T extends tOptionListItem>({
  children,
  items,
  dataTestId,
}: React.PropsWithChildren<tItemsListProps<T>>) {
  return (
    <Box>
      <List>
        {items?.map((item) => (
          <List.Item key={item.id} data-testid='list_item'>
            {children(item)}
          </List.Item>
        ))}
      </List>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Error:

> TS2322: Type '(item: T) => Element' is not assignable to type '(((item: T) => ReactNode) & string) | (((item: T) => ReactNode) & number) | (((item: T) => ReactNode) & false) | (((item: T) => ReactNode) & true) | (((item: T) => ReactNode) & ReactElement<...>) | (((item: T) => ReactNode) & ReactFragment) | (((item: T) => ReactNode) & ReactPortal)'.   Type '(item: T) => Element' is not assignable to type '((item: T) => ReactNode) & string'.     Type '(item: T) => Element' is not assignable to type 'string'.  ItemsList.tsx(7, 3): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & tItemsListProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'

I understand that prop `children: (item: T) => React.ReactNode` returns the wrong type, but in React 17 it worked and everything was correct.

Comment: Maybe this has to do with Typescript rather than React itself. Are you also using a newer version of Typescript?

Comment: I use TypeScript 4.9.4

Answer (score 0):

I changed returned function's type and solve this problem

```
function ItemsList<T extends tOptionListItem>({
  children,
  items,
  dataTestId,
}: tItemsListProps<T>) {
  return (
    <Box>
      <List>
        {items?.map((item) => (
          <List.Item key={item.id} data-testid='list_item'>
            {children(item)}
          </List.Item>
        ))}
      </List>
    </Box>
  );
}
```